# How to execute parent directive before child directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to write two angular directives, a parent and a child directive, to create sortable and cloneable widgets. The intended markup is:

```html
<div class="widget-container" data-sortable-widgets>
      <section class="widget" data-cloneable-widget></section>
<div>
```

However, the child directive seems to execute before the parent, before a certain element is available (its added by the parent):

```js
function SortableWidgetsDirective() {
    return {
        priority: 200,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find(".widget header").append($("<div class='widget-controls'></div>"));
            element.sortable({  });
        }
    };
}

function CloneableWidgetDirective() {
    return {
        priority: 100,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            // This directive wrongfully executes first so widget-controls is no available
            element.find("header .widget-controls").append($("<div class='clone-handle'></div>"));
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see i tried setting priority but I think because they're on different elements, it does not work.

How can I make the parent execute first?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Reasoning

`postLink()` is executed in reverse order, which means the child directive's `postLink()` will be called before the parent's (i.e. depth first). For some reason, this is the default behavior (`link()` actually refers to `postLink()`). Luckily  we also have `preLink()`, which works the other way around - we can utilize that to our benefit.

To illustrate this - the following snippet of code:

```js
app.directive('parent', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $log.info('parent pre');
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $log.info('parent post');
                }
            }
        }
    };
});

app.directive('child', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $log.info('child pre');
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $log.info('child post');
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

… will output the following:

```
> parent pre
> child pre
> child post
> parent post
```

See it [<kbd>live on plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDQkwSKrVRKEyJH7qejp?p=preview).

### Solution

If we want the parent directive's logic to be performed before the child's, we will explicitly use `preLink()`:

```js
function SortableWidgetsDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    iElement.find(".widget header").append($("<div class='widget-controls'></div>"));
                    iElement.sortable({});
                },
                post: angular.noop
            }
        }
    };
}

function CloneableWidgetDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    iElement.find("header .widget-controls").append($("<div class='clone-handle'></div>"));
                },
                post: angular.noop
            }
        }
    };
}
```

### References

- [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service on the AngularJS docs.

---

### Post Scriptum

- You are correct, by the way - `priority` is meant for use with directives that share the same element.
- `angular.noop` is just an empty method that returns nothing. If you still want to use the `postLink()` functions, just place the function declaration instead, as you would normally do, i.e.:

  ```
  post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
  ```
- Be ware of the use of `templateUrl`, as *“ Because the template loading is asynchronous the compilation/linking is suspended until the template is loaded ”* <sup>[[source]](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-)</sup>. As a result, the order of execution will be disrupted. You can remedy this by including the template inlined in the `template` property instead.

Comment: Can you please explain angular.noop? What if I still want to use link function after should it go instead of angular.noop or outside compile?

Comment: do you know that this completely breaks down when supplying a templateUrl? http://plnkr.co/edit/1OlW6UuhvkfzD27yz2Vc?p=preview 
This is a problem for me as I need to use one. What do you suggest?

Comment: yes, see another update - it's worth noting that in the answer body.

Comment: actually my template is already on the page in a`<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template></script>`. Can I force angular to not load it asynchronously to get around this?

Comment: it's pre-loaded to the template cache, but the directive will load it regadless. so, no way out here - just put the template inlined. that's the limitations at the moment, i'm afraid (hope i'm proved wrong here...)

Comment: The way i got around this was to use template, like mentioned. But to inject $templateCache and do template: $templateCache.get('url.tpl.html'). Neat little trick to keep the pre/post linking order.

Comment: sounds interesting, @j_walker_dev. please post it as an answer, so others may benefit from it :)

Comment: This answer continues to be useful to me. I'd like to add the order of controller initialization for these directives. The order is:

parent controller,
parent pre,
child controller,
child pre,
child post,
parent post,