# Angular transcluded directive as sibling scope incompatible with child directive's require: "^parent" setting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having an issue with the way AngularJS handles transcluded scopes for directives. It is known that a transclude's scope is a sibling of its directive's scope, not a child. [Shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788289/1267778)

However, I have a situation with a child directive:

```
 <div price-chart>
      <div volume-indicator></div>
 </div>
```

The priceChart directive has a `transclude: true, template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"` but the (transcluded) volumeIndicator requires the parent to be a priceChart, not the sibling.

```
function VolumeIndicatorDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        controller: "VolumeIndicatorController",
        require: ["^priceChart", "volumeIndicator"],
        compile: function compile(element, attrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink($scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                    var priceChart = controllers[0];
                    var volumeIndicator = controllers[1];
                    priceChart.addIndicator(volumeIndicator);
                },
                post: angular.noop
            };
        }
    };
}
```

If Angular had a sibling selector for controllers that would solve the issue:

```
require: ["+priceChart", "volumeIndicator"],
```

However, this doesn't exist so what can I do?

As per comment from zeroflagL I tried `element.parent().controller()` to access the directive controller but it seems to get the nearest `ng-controller` specifically and skips over directive controllers.

Comment: From the docs: "Locate the required controller by searching the ELEMENT'S parent" - The scope doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried this and it seems to skip over directive controllers and gets the nearest parent `ng-controller`. Tried element.controller() and every possible parent (parent(), parent().parent(), etc). updated OP

Comment: What I meant was that your code should work. What error do you get? And as for `element.parent().controller()` - It has to be `element.parent().controller('priceChart')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, `require`'s '^' syntax will try to *"locate the required controller by searching the element's parents"*. Scope prototypal inheritance doesn't play a role here, so your code should work as expected.

And indeed **[it does](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/hG2c7/)** !

Comment: You're right, actually it was an even higher level parent directive causing the issue by use of "templateUrl" http://jsfiddle.net/hG2c7/5/. This causes the directive to load asynchronously and breaks the parent/child linking order, making volumeIndicator link before its parent, and therefore missing the controller. This is described very well in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081483/1267778

Comment: Unfortuantely templateUrl still loads async even when it's included using a static template script tag. The way I got around this by firing an event from the parent when it was done loading and listening to the event on the child to proceed.