# Passing element attributes from parent to child with Angular JS 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with Angular JS. I have two directives.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myFirstDirective', function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                var myAttributeToPass = attr.myFirstDirective;
                scope.myAttr = myAttributeToPass;
            },
            controller: 'MyFirstController'
        }
    })
    .controller('MyFirstController', function($scope){
        this.returnTheParameter = function(){
            return $scope.myAttr;
        }
    })
    .directive('mySecondDirective', function(){
        return {
            require : ['ngModel', '^myFirstDirective'],
            link : function($scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                var ngModel = ctrls[0];
                var myFirstCtrl = ctrls[1];

                var theParamOfFirst = myFirstCtrl.returnTheParameter();
            }
        }
    });
```

I init my first value with a string :

```
<div my-first-directive="foobar"> (... => my second directive is inside) </div>
```

My problem is in the life cycle, the returned value is always undefined because the controller is called before the link. When i do an isolated scope, with :

```
scope: {
    "myProp": "@myFirstDirective"
}
```

That's works but i don't want to isolate the scope...

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the order in which the operations are taking place.

It sounds like you will need to compile things in a specific order. In which case I would like to refer you to this post: [How to execute parent directive before child directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081140/how-to-execute-parent-directive-before-child-directive) so I don't borrow the full thunder of another person's explanation.

Ultimately you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
    return {
        compile: function(){
          return{
            pre:function (scope, elem, attr) {
              var myAttributeToPass = attr.myFirstDirective;
              scope.myAttr = myAttributeToPass;
          },
            post: angular.noop
          };
        },
        controller: 'MyFirstController'
    };
```

for your first directive and for the second directive:

```
    return {
        require : ['^myFirstDirective'],
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude){
          return{
            pre: angular.noop,
            post: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
              var ngModel = attrs.ngModel;
              var theParamOfFirst = ctrls[0].returnTheParameter();
            }
          };
        }
    };
```

The `angular.noop` above is just an empty method returning nothing.
For a working example feel free to browse the plunk I threw together (http://plnkr.co/edit/pe07vQ1BtTc043gFZslD?p=preview).